# Getting day of the week (mon, tues, wed) based on Y:m:d format saved in database field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table called `'transactions'` with the field `'actualdate'` that has the date of each row saved like `2014-09-13`.

I'm displaying the results using this query:

```
"SELECT id,actualdate, SUM(points) FROM transactions GROUP BY DAY(actualdate) ORDER BY id DESC limit 7"
```

Then displaying the results with:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $row['actualdate'];
    echo " ";
    echo $row['SUM(points)'];
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Is it possible to echo what day of the week it was for each summed result based on the date the way it's formatted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course, you can use `Datetime` in this case:

```
$row['actualdate'] = '2014-09-13';
$date = new DateTime($row['actualdate']);
echo $date->format('l'); // l represents Monday, Tuesday,
// in this case "Saturday"

// For three letter representations use this:
echo $date->format('D'); // Sat
```

Applying it:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo "<li>";
    $date = new DateTime($row['actualdate']);
    echo $date->format('D');
    echo " ";
    echo $row['SUM(points)'];
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: This is cool, but it's only displaying todays day. I need the query to work out what day each of my 'actualdate' row values fell on.

Comment: @user1654748 wait, you did change the values to fit into yours right? i just gave `$row['actualdate'] = '2014-09-13';` an example, of course in your loop, just substitute it to the one you're fetching

Comment: I'm sorry, It's been a really long day. Can you please provide what you mean? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @user1654748 check my revision, that is what i mean, just use it inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

if only what day it is then

```
$day=date( 'l', strtotime($row['actualdate']) );
```